# View definition is not getting updated in SQL Server

Tags: sql, view, sql-server-2012

I have a fairly complex view, generated using SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle, but with some logical as well as some syntax errors.

But, when I update the SQL statement of it (with *right click -> design* and then update the sql in text-area), the new SQL is shown when I *right click -> Script view as -> Create/Alter to*, but when I open the view design with *right click -> design*, it does not show the updated SQL statement.

And since the original view definition has syntax errors, I am getting error :
`SQL text cannot be represented in the grid pane and diagram pane.`

I have tried restarting the SQL instance and also with `sp_refreshview <ViewName>`, but with no success.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (64-bit) on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-bit).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is this causing a problem? The visual designer is best avoided anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The visual designer is not capable of visualising every construct which can be used in a view. Syntax errors will also cause this error.

If you get this error, your only option is to not use the visual designer, but edit the SQL by hand.

You can do this using

```
Right-Click -> Script View As -> ALTER to -> New Query Editor Window
```

Once you have corrected the errors, and can successfully run `ALTER VIEW`, you ***may*** be able to use the designer.

Comment: I am still not able to use the designer even though I have resolved all errors, but it seems I have no other option !